# How to retrieve stored procedure return value with Dapper

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dapper

I have a stored procedure of this form:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddProduct
    (@ProductID varchar(10),
     @Name  nvarchar(150)
    )
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 ProductID FROM Products 
               WHERE ProductID = @ProductID)
        RETURN -11
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Products ([AgentID], [Name])
        VALUES (@AgentID, @Name)

        RETURN @@ERROR
    END
```

I have this C# to call the stored procedure, but I can't seem to get a correct value form it:

```
var returnCode = cn.Query(
    sql: "AddProduct",
    param: new { @ProductID = prodId, @Name = name },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

How can I ensure that the `returnCode` variable will contain the value returned from either the `RETURN -11` or the `RETURN @@ERROR` lines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To enable use of the `RETURN` statement in SQL the C# becomes...

```
var _params = new DynamicParameters{ @ProductID = prodId, @Name = name };
_params.Add(
    name: "@RetVal",
    dbType: DbType.Int32,
    direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
    );
var returnCode = cn.Execute(
    sql: "AddProduct",
    param: _params,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
return _params.Get<int>("@RetVal");
```

It's not the implementation I was hoping for, but it works.

Comment: It's not possible to get both the result set AND the return value, right?

Comment: @MattW I tried this solution but it throws an exception because there are more parameters in the _params than in the stored

Comment: How is `new DynamicParameters{ @ProductID = prodId, @Name = name };` valid C# syntax?  I just get an error 'DynamicParameters does not contain a definition for 'ProductID'`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `SELECT` to return the values from your stored procedure. Also you should specify a return type on the dapper call:

```
RETURN -11
```

becomes

```
SELECT -11
```

and the dapper call becomes:

```
var returnCode = cn.Query<int>(..
```

I have implemented this pattern several times and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not allowed to comment:

Matt Ws Answer worked for me. By running connection.Query(...) there is also the result like an scalar or anything else obtained from stored procedure per SELECT.

I added the dynamic parameters different:

```
var _params = new DynamicParameters();
_params.Add("@ProductID", prodId);
_params.Add("@Name", name);
_params.Add(
    name: "@RetVal",
    dbType: DbType.Int32,
    direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
    );
var result= cn.Query(
    sql: "AddProduct",
    param: _params,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
return _params.Get<int>("@RetVal");
```